# powerquery filter TopN values for each year

Tags: excel, filter, powerquery

i have a data set for each country and each year.

question : i want to filter Gross Amount topN for each year with PowerQuery.

i can get a result with this code only for one year but i need all years' data with top10(N) in one list.

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Export Country", type text}, {"Gross Export", Int64.Type}, {"Share", type number}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Imp/Exp", type text}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Year", Order.Ascending}, {"Gross Export", Order.Descending}}),
#"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows",10) 
in #"Kept First Rows"
```

Workaround : I created lists for each year separately and then merge them but it is a long shoot. Expected result in the sheet "Export_Top10"

Thank you for your help.

[Data File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nerh6jZ7ApWu1lCrgyakfRdfAu_JPIrg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100599386090580961037&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: @JvdV i hope my edit clears more...

Comment: @JvdV i searched the internet and tried of course but couldnt find a way to do it , thats why i posted here to get help. and this website and all supporters here gives free support as far as i know...

Comment: See [ask] a question with an [mcve]. Another usefull link for you to read is found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Edit your question accordingly. Don't just say what you want, don't link to external files, show what you researched, show what you tried, show where you are stuck, show the desired results.....just do a lot more then just say what you want. People will think you are just seeking a free service.

Comment: and there are some posts to solve with PowerBi but nothing with PowerQuery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238659/discussion-between-umut-k-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of grouping on [Year], and then within each group, sorting on [Amount] and adding an index. Then you expand the data and filter the index for the top X [Amount] numbers you are looking for. In the code I pick up the top 10, in the image, the top 3

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Year"}, {{"All", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_,{{"Amount", Order.Descending}}),"Index",1,1), type table}}),
#"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Amount", "Index"}, {"Amount", "Index"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded All", each ([Index] < 11))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Sample before/after picking top 3:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method that also involves Grouping.

But, instead of Sorting all the entire subtable and adding an Index column, I sort a List of the Gross Exports and Select only those rows where Gross Exports is >= than the tenth highest.

Note that this method will return **all** rows in the event of a **tie**.  So if two countries are tied for exports in a given year, you might have 11 rows returned instead of 10.

```
let
    Source = #"Table1 (3)",

//Group by year and extract top 10
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Year"}, {
        {"Top Ten", (t)=> Table.SelectRows(t, each [Gross Export]> List.Sort(t[Gross Export],Order.Descending){10})}}),

//remove year column since we will expand it in the correct order in next step
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Year"}),

//expand the top ten table
    #"Expanded Top Ten" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Top Ten", 
        {"Export Country", "Gross Export", "Share", "Year", "Imp/Exp"}, {"Export Country", "Gross Export", "Share", "Year", "Imp/Exp"})
in
    #"Expanded Top Ten"
```

**example results showing only top *3***
[image]

Comment: thats interesting, I never thought about doing it that way

Comment: @ron rosenfeld thank you, as if there were much more rows, this would work faster i guess and tie possibility is almost zero )))

Comment: I'd be curious which is faster. Let me know when you try it

Comment: @Ron hi again, i tried to use your way in another table but i couldnt expand the grouped because it does not contain any columns... what am i missing ?


    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Hesap Grubu] = "320")),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"FirmaID", "Şube ID", "Hesap No"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Toplam]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"FirmaID", "Şube ID", "Hesap No"}, {
        {"Top Ten", (t)=> Table.SelectRows(t, each [Total]> List.Sort(t[Total],Order.Descending){10})}})
in

Comment: @Ron I have 3 columns to group, "FirmaID" , "Şube ID", "Hesap No". First I have to group by these so i can find the balances of the companies before ranking (Hesap No)

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @horseyride i figured out the solution

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Export Country", type text}, {"Gross Export", Int64.Type}, {"Share", type number}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Imp/Exp", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Year"}, {{"All", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_,{{"Gross Export", Order.Descending}}),"Index",1,1), type table}}),
#"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Export Country", "Gross Export", "Share", "Imp/Exp", "Index"}, {"Export Country", "Gross Export", "Share", "Imp/Exp", "Index"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded All",{{"Gross Export", type number}, {"Share", Percentage.Type}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each [Index] <= 10),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```